# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PostsController#edit "Couldn't find Place with 'id'=17"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, controller, foreign-keys

I am having a problem with editing a post. When i click edit and when its suppose to redirect me to the page to edit i get an error. I have two tables one is `posts` the other is `places`.  I have a foreign key called `post_id` in my `places` table. Every post `has_one` place. I understand that my "edit" with "place" in the `PostController` is not called correctly since it needs to be referenced probably. How would I do that to make the code work??

PostsController:

```rails
class PostsController < ApplicationController

before_action :authenticate_user!, :except => [:show, :index, :new]

before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

before_action :owned_post, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]  

  def index
    @post = Post.new
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def show

    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new

    @post = current_user.posts.build

    @posts = Post.all


  end

  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)


    if @post.save
      flash[:success] = "Your post has been created!"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Your new post couldn't be created!  Please check the form."
      render :new
    end
  end

  def find
    @place = Place.new
  end

  def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @place = Place.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
     if @post.update(post_params)
      flash[:success] = "Post updated."
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "Update failed.  Please check the form."
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @post.destroy

    flash[:success] = "Your Post has been removed."
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  private



  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:image, :caption, :latitude, :longitude)
  end

  def set_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def owned_post  
  unless current_user == @post.user
    flash[:alert] = "That post doesn't belong to you!"
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end  

end
```

I would also like to add places to this form when i create a new post so that both places and posts table populate with the correct fields in relation to each other.

Form that creates the post:

```rails
<%= form_image_select(@post) %>
        <%= simple_form_for @post, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
          <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
              <%= f.error_notification %>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="form-group text-center">
              <h4>Upload an image (this is required):</h4>
              <%= f.input :image, label: false, input_html: { onChange: 'loadFile(event)' } %>
            </div>
            <%= simple_fields_for place.new do |o| %>
            <div class="form-group text-center">
            <%= o.input :address, label: false, placeholder: "search", class: 'controls', id: "pac-input" %>
           <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">

            </div>


          <% end %>

            <div class="form-group text-center">
              <%= f.input :caption, label: false, placeholder: 'Add your caption' %>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group text-center">
              <%= f.button :submit, class: 'btn-success btn-block' %>
            </div>
          </div>
        <% end %>
```

New error log:

Started GET "/posts/17/edit" for ::1 at 2016-05-08 05:59:33 +0900
Processing by PostsController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"17"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 16]]
  Post Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 17]]
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 16]]
  Place Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "places".* FROM "places" WHERE "places"."post_id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["post_id", 17]]
  Rendered posts/_form.html.erb (14.0ms)
  Rendered posts/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (14.9ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 21ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `place' for #<#<Class:0x007f92b27c7738>:0x007f92bb24b288>):
    17:               <h4>Upload an image (this is required):</h4>
    18:               <%= f.input :image, label: false, input_html: { onChange: 'loadFile(event)' } %>
    19:             </div>
    20:             <%= simple_fields_for place.new do |o| %>
    21:             <div class="form-group text-center">
    22:             <%= o.input :address, label: false, placeholder: "search", class: 'controls', id: "pac-input" %>
    23:            <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
  app/views/posts/_form.html.erb:20:in`block in _app_views_posts__form_html_erb__1067044067393355525_70134077243420'
  app/views/posts/_form.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_posts__form_html_erb__1067044067393355525_70134077243420'
  app/views/posts/edit.html.erb:2:in`_app_views_posts_edit_html_erb__4372466127864082923_70134042275460'

Comment: You are finding both post and place with the same id. They don't necessarily have the same id. Also as per your description you should have place_id inside the post and not the other way around. since post has one place but one place can have many posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your edit action, you're trying to find your Place by `:id`, which is the Post's id. Assuming you have a `has_one` `:place` relationship in your Post model you can do:

```
def edit
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @place = @post.place;
end
```

Setting `@post` is redundant since you do it in `set_post`, so your edit action can become:

```
def edit
  @place = @post.place;
end
```

Comment: aww i see! yes it got rid of the first error now it says: NameError in Posts#edit "undefined local variable or method `place'"

Comment: Thats because the association/relationship is missing between post and place models. Add this to **post.rb** `has_one :place` and inside **place.rb** add `belongs_to: post`

Comment: hey meer ty! Iv had both `has_one :place` and `belongs_to: post` already involved in the models! what else could have caused this?

Comment: if possible, can you paste the complete error log here?

Comment: On line 20 you're using `place` without it being defined. I think you should be using `@place` instead of `place.new`.

Comment: Replace line 20 of you code with `<%= f.simple_fields_for :place do |do%>` also inside you yore post model add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :place` if not already there.